# generate string list (n length) with m possible chars

Tags: php, memory, xampp

I need to generate a String List with N-Length and M possible chars. Currently I'm using PHP/XAMPP.

My function works great for generating the strings with 62 possible chars (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) and up to the length of 4 chars. However, when I want to generate longer strings I'm running out of memory.

I've set the memory limit, but I'm still running out of memory.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

the error I get:

```
Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1858600960) (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 51
```

how can I solve this problem? Should I switch to another language for more performance when generating the string list?

EDIT, the code I'm working with:

```
http://pastebin.com/f6pA6Ra0
```

Comment: I think you need refactoring your code, because I think you use regex and you algoritmth get recursive. p.s. sorry for my English.

Comment: @Naumov, thank you for your answer. I'm not using regex but yes, the function I'm using is recursive

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: if you use recursive function she can recicled

Comment: @SergeiBeregov - http://pastebin.com/f6pA6Ra0

Comment: You need simple algoritmth because you alogritm `x^3` this thery you for each array over `238327` only for 3 interation is bad. `memory_limit` work but you fisical memory is lost. You sure what you need get array?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get a random string with 5 length with M as possible characters?

then I propose taking a random element of M 5 times, and not making an array of *every single possibility* (which is 916'132'832 possibilities (62^5) with this array of chars and length of 5 !)

here is a non-recursive function that returns a random string where you can define the size.

```
function sampling($size){
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    $output = '';
    $charLength = strlen($chars) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $charLength);
        $output .= $chars[$n];
    }
    return $output; 
}
```

if I misunderstood your intentions and you really want to get all possibilities I am sorry ;)